# react native: how to unregister a listener/service?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, listener

I've a list of items. Each item can be displayed in `MyComponent`, by passing it's `itemId`. To listen on changes of the selected item, I'm passing `myService`:

```
<MyComponent myService={myService} id={itemId}/>
```

The component fetches the item details and starts listening to the service:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchItemDetails(this.props.id); // fetch the item details

    this.props.myService.listensTo('eventId', () => { 
        // something changed, fetch again ... 
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // reset / unregister the listener for this instance 
}
```

**Problem**: the listener is registered everytime I mount `MyComponent`, which becomes a problem with multiple instances.

I'd like to listen only to the active, mounted component and unlisten as soon as it's unmounted.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the function that you are using as callback. Usually what event listeners do is keep an internal structure of all the callback functions that have to be invoked when an event happens, and so, when you want to stop listening, you have to tell the event dispatcher which is the function that has to be excluded from the list. Since the only thing that gives you that information is the reference to the callback function itself. I would do the following:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.myListener = this.myListener.bind(this); // Do this only if necessary
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchItemDetails(this.props.id); // fetch the item details

    this.props.myService.listensTo('eventId', myListener);
}

myListener(){
    //...
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   // reset / unregister the listener for this instance
   this.props.myService.deregister('eventId', myListener);
}
```

The important thing is to keep the reference to the function, that's why it is important to put the binding in the constructor.

Comment: great, upvote .. I need a consultation: as a top user in *react native* tag, do you think is learning it worthy?! Someone says it's perfect, someone else says that's a terrible idea .. So I'm confused, I want to make a mobile application *(both for Android and iOS operation systems)*, well, is it possible to make professional apps by *react native*? Or *react native* just let us to make beginner apps? Also what about the quality of apps which have been created by *react native*? thanks

Comment: Mmm... I also was a bit reluctant at first, but I now think that RN is pretty good at handling large/professional applications. Even though it is still difficult to do some tasks, like background jobs or push notifications, the library keeps adding more functionality with each release, and the stability of every new version is also higher (the release cycle is slowing down as a consequence). It also doesn't take too much time to learn, so I'd say it is a safe investment.